# Where did date-time "add [custom] format" go in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, datetime

In D6 this was located in,
`Site Configuration >> date & time >> formats >> add format`
Where is this in D7?

I found this Drupal.SE question: [Date value to different date format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/date-value-to-different-date-format) explaining the code to create a custom format, but it doesn't say in which file to make the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration -> Regional & Language -> Date and time -> Formats -> Add format.

You end up at `/admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/add`.